# Find command line of program with PEB?

Tags: windows, command-line

I need find the command line of program with [PEB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Environment_Block).

I use FS:[0x30] to find PEB

```
     int wmain(int argc, WCHAR *argv[])
{

 PVOID pebAddress =( void * ) __readfsdword( 0x30 ); /* get the PEB address */
PVOID rtlUserProcParamsAddress;

ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(),(PCHAR)pebAddress+ 0x10,
    &rtlUserProcParamsAddress, /* we'll just read directly into our variable */
    sizeof(PVOID),
    NULL
    );

UNICODE_STRING commandLine;

 ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (PCHAR)rtlUserProcParamsAddress + 0x40,&commandLine, sizeof(commandLine), NULL);

 WCHAR * commandLineContents;

 commandLineContents = (WCHAR *)malloc(commandLine.Length);

 ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), commandLine.Buffer,commandLineContents, commandLine.Length, NULL);

 printf("%.*S\n", commandLine.Length / 2, commandLineContents);


}
```

but it does not work. I need use only PEB not `GetCommandLine(void);`

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me on Windows 7 with VC2010. `printf` might be defined as `wprintf` which treats %S as ANSI string. It's a long shot as that would also cause it to complain about the format string being non-Unicode. Try outputting the string using MessageBoxW to be sure you're treating everything as Unicode.

BTW, you don't need to use ReadProcessMemory when you're reading from your own process.

Comment: ""BTW, you don't need to use ReadProcessMemory when you're reading from your own process."" how?

Comment: The address you get from __readfsdword is in your own process. Just treat as a pointer and dereference/memcpy. `PUNICODE_STRING cl = (PUNICODE_STRING)((*(LPBYTE*)((LPBYTE)__readfsdword(0x30)+0x10))+0x40);`

Answer (score -1):

Why would you need to use the PEB? Have you looked at the contents of `argv` at all?

And what's the (to me) scary looking `commandLine.Length / 2` for in your code...?